# Azure Function - HTTP trigger - Intermittent 502 errors

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a Azure Function app with a HTTP trigger endpoint that intermittently returns 502 errors.
I've not been able to see anyting in the Application Insights logs that would point to the endpoint exceeding the 430 second limit. Max request time is around 7 seconds.
The endpoint is connecting to a Azure Redis cache and in case of the data not being cached getting the data from a Azure SQL database using EF Core.
The function app is running in a dedicated app service plan.
I've read this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-http-502-http-503 without it helping me find a solution to the issue.
Like this question https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/428059/c-azure-function-returning-502-bad-gateway-but-no.html I'm not seeing any errors in the AI logs.

Any thoughts appreciated.
Regards, Oskar

Comment: I've faced 502 errors in the past and they were related with limited resources (tcp connections in my case). Try scaling up the app service plan.

Comment: Have been running diagnostics tools but haven't found anything yet and the CPU, memory seems fine. Might be TCP, I'll have a look into that. Thanks :)